# Probability of events containing the phrase "for some $t$"

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $T>0$ and let $(U_t)_{0\leq t\leq T}$ and $(V_t)_{0\leq t\leq T}$ be two independent families of uniformly distributed random variables on the interval $[0,1]$. Also assume that $(U_t)_t$ is independent of $(V_t)_t$. Intuitively, it should hold that
$$\mathbb P( U_t = V_t \text{ for some }t\in[0,T]) = 0.$$
But how do I deal with these "for some" statements in events? Can I do something like a law of total probability approach here that goes like
$$\mathbb P( U_t = V_t \text{ for some }t\in[0,T]) = \int_0^T \mathbb P( U_s = V_s) ds = 0?$$
If this approach is correct, I would be very grateful for more steps justifying the first equality above.

EDIT:

Thinking about it some more I realized that the approach should not work since for example intuitively
$$\mathbb P(U_t>1/2 \text{ for some }t\in[0,T]) = 1$$ but
$$\int_0^T \mathbb P(U_s>1/2)ds$$
does not always have to be equal to $1$. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What is your definition for "independent families" why does it prohibit letting $U_t = V_t$?

Comment: Sorry that was badly formulated. I mean that the two stochastic processes $(U_t)_t$ and $(V_t)_t$ are each independent and also $(U_t)_t$ is independent of $(V_t)_t$.

Comment: I think it might be important to fully define the sample space and $\sigma$-algebra here.  The existence of these processes isn't clear to me, nor is the measurability of the event $\{U_t = V_t \text{ for some } t \in [0,T]\}$.